# Which is more popular, Freemarker or Velocity?

Tags: templates, velocity, freemarker, template-engine, popularity

I'm about to invest resources in revamping my email system around a templating engine Freemarker or Velocity.  They both seem comparable in terms of features and support.  Which is more popular or has more steam behind it?

Comment: depends who you ask,  I doubt anyone has a reliable statistics on which is actually used more often.  They both have good things about them, but I prefer freemarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about them going away, i wouldn't.  Both have been around for ages untold and have plenty of resources out there.  Personally, i got involved with Velocity because i despised the angle brackets of Freemarker's old syntax.  But now you can use square brackets in Freemarker.  Likewise, many people used to choose Freemarker for better performance or more advanced features, but Velocity fixed a lot of the performance issues and VelocityTools provides a huge wealth of features.   Seriously, i don't think you can go wrong with either of them anymore.  Flip a coin or something. :)

Comment: It's more than just going away... I want to have an easier time hiring people, finding good documentation/books, tools that work with the template framework, etc..

Comment: Ah, then i think you'll probably find slightly more people/docs/tools with Velocity.  Due to being an ASF project, it is slightly higher profile, i would guess.

Comment: And for the record, neither has a lot of "steam" right now.  They are both very mature and popular and thus have a lot of momentum, but they have both been "good enough" for years so new work on them has been minimal for a long time.  I'm sure eventually one or both will fire up the dev engines again, but right now they are stable, quiet projects.